# PHP Code Editor for Windows

Tags: php, windows, editor, textmate

Currently I use TextMate for PHP editing on MAC. I would like to know what good editors for WINDOWS (comparable to TextMate) are.

The most important feature I expect that the editor should support is the "auto-complete of code snippets", like:

```
p (tab key)  =>  outputs: <?php ?>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Duplicate to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70120/which-text-code-editor-on-linux-is-most-similar-to-textmate

Comment: @TheJumpingFrog that thread is mostly for Linux right ? I am looking for a windows solution

Comment: If you have high configuration in your computer, go for phpstorm. Else, phpdesigner.

Comment: I use the Zeus editor and it as a template feature that can be easily configured to do this.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I'm using the full-fledged **[JetBrains PhpStorm IDE](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/)**, and I love it. (paid)

Before that, I used **[MPSoftware phpDesigner](http://www.mpsoftware.dk/phpdesigner.php)**, which is also great (and fast!). (also paid)

If you're not looking for a full IDE, but only a text editor. I suggest **[Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/)**. (free)

Answer (score 1):

Netbeans
notepad++

all of them are free

Answer (score 1):

[Sublime Text 2 (beta)](http://www.sublimetext.com/dev) is very similar to TextMate in philosophy but more "modern" and more actively and transparently developped. It works with TextMate's snippet mechanism, it's cross-platform (Win/Mac/Linux), it's extensible…

Aside from ST2, there are many PHP-oriented text editors on Windows but I don't think many of them have a proper "snippet expansion" system. However, most IDE, nowadays, do.

Or, if you are ready for a deep dive, Vim or Emacs blow away both ST 2 and TM.